# How do I get content of a plist file in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, plist

So I created I plist file that get a list of all libs licenses on my podfile (following this tutorial: https://johncodeos.com/easy-way-to-list-third-party-libraries-licenses-in-your-ios-app/)

But now how can I get the content of this file? Every example that I used comes with a file path nil. What am I doing wrong?

Example code:

```
let path = Bundle.path(forResource: "Acknowledgements", ofType: "plist", inDirectory: "Licenses")
```

My plist file structure:
[image: plist structure]

I would like to get title and footerText of every Item in my PreferenceSpecifiers. How could I do that?

PS.: I've never work with plist/bundle.setting files before, so forgive if I'm asking something dumb. I've read about but it/s still cloudy to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `url(forResource:withExtension:)` instead of the path. You can use this function (replace MyPlistFile.plist with the name of your file):

```
// Provide the key of the entry you need to read
    func getStringValueFromPlist(forKey key: String) -> String {
        guard let fileURL = url(forResource: "MyPlistFile.plist", withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Can't find \(fileName)")
        }

        let contents = NSDictionary(contentsOf: fileURL) as? [String: String] ?? [:]

        return contents[key] ?? ""
    }
```

To get a nested dictionary, you need to change the type, from `String` to a dictionary type, like `[String: String]`, then read inside that dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:

```swift
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YourPlist", ofType: "plist")!
    let plist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    let value = plist?.object(forKey: "PlistKey")
```

First of all you should search path for existing plist file and then convert its content to the Dictionary for access to values by string keys.

Be careful about force unwrap (`!`)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).